# JavaScript p5js WEBGL transparency color of images in DEPTH_FUNC not working

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I have problem with depth sorting in my 2D game based on WEBGL, I just wanted to make z-axis depth sorting, it works, but the transparency color is not transparent...

I made some test code for this situation, its becouse i render flag as last image, and i want to get the player and knife over this flag, but transparency of the player and knife not working and hides the flag. As in the image below. Is there any way to fix it? I want to make layers in my game by z-axis, bigger Z, the image will be more in the front, in topper layer. In classic Processing i was making layer system like hint(ENABLE_DEPTH_SORT).

- p5.js version: v0.10.2 October 14, 2019 and v1.1.9 July 22, 2020 (in example code below)
- Web browser and version: Google Chrome 86.0.4240.198 64bit
- Operating System: Windows 10 OS Version 2004 (Build 19041.630)

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4yHDg.png)

**index.html**

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.1.9/p5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <style>body{margin:0;padding:0;background-color: rgb(19,19,19);}</style>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

**script.js**

```
var img_knife, img_player, img_flag; // images variables
function setup(){
    // setup canvas
    createCanvas(600, 600, WEBGL);
    // setup gl to depth render
    var gl = document.getElementById('defaultCanvas0').getContext('webgl');
    gl.getParameter(gl.DEPTH_FUNC);
    // load images
    img_knife = loadImage('https://i.ibb.co/wpJ1HNn/knife.png');
    img_player = loadImage('https://i.ibb.co/xYmSs5t/player.png');
    img_flag = loadImage('https://i.ibb.co/t2n6n9f/flag.png');

    gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, img_knife);
}
function draw(){
    background(19);
    // Draw player image
    push();
    translate(30,20,10);
    tint(255,255,0)
    image(img_player, 0, 0);
    pop();
    // Draw knife image
    push();
    translate(120,95,15);
    rotate(PI)
    image(img_knife, 0, 0);
    pop();
    // Draw flag image
    push();
    translate(0,0,0);
    image(img_flag, 0, 0);
    pop();
}
```

Comment: does p5 take care of enabling blending for you?